Generate unique substrings for each string
String Compression - Compress each string to unique substring identifiers. Algorithm takes too long to run.
Hello everyone,
I am constructing a crosswalk between string identifiers of two datasets. For this reason, I am trying to "compress" the strings in both datasets to substring(s) with lowest number of characters that uniquely identify them.
For an example, consider a dataset of the following:



Raw ID
Compressed ID




Apple
Apple


Appha
pph


pple
pple


Apps
pps


Alpha
lp,Al


Apples
es



In this example, Apples was compressed to "es", because no other id contained "es" and "es" had the lowest number of characters in such unique substrings.
Additionally, Alpha was compressed to "lp" and "Al", separated by a (,) as they have the same number of characters.
The idea is to use these compressed strings and apply a containment criterion across both datasets to generate a crosswalk.
I have thought about the following simple algorithm to get these lowest-character unique substrings: For each string, get every single substring. Check for each substring of each string whether that substring exists elsewhere (so that it is a substring of another string), if not (therefore it is unique) note the character length of this unique substring. Now, pick the substrings with lowest number of characters for each string.
Here is the python code I've written to implement the algorithm above:
def get_substrings(string):
    """Generate all substrings of a string."""
    substrings = set()
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(string) + 1):
            substrings.add(string[i:j])
    return substrings

def preprocess_dataset(dataset):
    """Generate all substrings for each string in the dataset."""
    all_substrings = {}
    for string in dataset:
        all_substrings[string] = get_substrings(string)
    return all_substrings

def get_minimal_unique_substrings(string, all_substrings):
    min_length = len(string)
    minimal_substrings = []

    for substring in all_substrings[string]:
        if all(substring not in all_substrings[other_string] for other_string in all_substrings if other_string != string):
            if len(substring) < min_length:
                min_length = len(substring)
                minimal_substrings = [substring]
            elif len(substring) == min_length and substring not in minimal_substrings:
                minimal_substrings.append(substring)

    return ",".join(set(minimal_substrings))

However, the problem is, this code takes too much time to run, given my dataset consists of around 70million observations. I was wondering whether anyone has an alternative suggestion to the algorithm above, or any suggestions on how to speed it up. I am also open to your opinions on other string compression methods.
Thank you! Any hints and help will be appreciated. Best wishes.
Final edit: Fixed Compressed ID outputs in the table above.

Wouldn't Appha compress to pph in that example?

@JohnGordon You are right! I fixed the mistake.

Note. I expect that finding the optimal answer is NP hard. Therefore optimal is not going to be efficient. So I'd look for "acceptable speed and quality" instead of optimal.

That’s an interesting problem. At first, it looks NP-hard, since there is at least n! mappings from input words W to possible abbreviations A. At least, because one abbreviation is the full word, not abbriviated at all + all substrings of the word for each word!
Suppose average length of input word \in W is k, than size of A is approximately n * k^2. So the number of mappings is (n * k^2) * (n * k^2 - 1) * (n * k^2 - 2) * … * (n * k^2 - n) >= n!.
And you would like to find the most optimal mapping, that is mapping with sum of length of each assigned abbreviation over all input words to be the lowest possible. In your table example, that would be 19.
But this can be actually solved in polynomial time. Here is the solution.
You first need a set of “allowed” abbreviations. These are abbreviations which do not collide with other input words and are unique. That is in your example for example pps or pple, and not pp. This can be constructed by creating an empty dictionary. Then iterate over every input word w_i \in W, all input words, and generate all possible abbreviations for w_i. If it’s present, increase value by 1, if not, set it’s value to 1. The key is the abbreviation. After iterating over all input words, you have a dictionary of size O(n * l^2), where l is size of longest input word. Constructing it took the same. Now transform this dictionary to set, which only contains abbreviations with value equal to 1. This way you eliminated all duplicate abbreviations and you are left only with allowed ones. Lets call this set A*.
Now iterate again over all w_i \in W, and again iterate over all abbreviations a_i for w_i. Start from the shortest one - one letters only, two letters only, …, w_i. Check if a_i is in A*. If so map w_i to a_i. There is at least one a_i in A*, that is whole w_i under the presumption that words in W are unique. Since we tried from the shortest abbreviations, the first one found in A* is the shortest allowed abbreviation for w_i. Continue for all words in W.
You end up with the most optimal mapping. Its valid, because we mapped to abbreviations from A*, which are unique and do not collide for any two words. That is implied from the way A* was constructed. And the mapping is optimal. Since we always mapped w_i to shortest allowed abbreviation.
We managed to find this mapping in O(3 * n * l^2) ~ O(n * l^2), and if l, maximum input word length is constant, O(n). Where n is of course input words count.
PS: I just realized that it is not sufficent the input words are unique, it also cannot contain input words which are substrings of each other. In your example, thats apple and apples. You have apple for apple as abbreviation, but that is not unique substring. Apples has also substring apple. How would you want this case to be handled? In this case, in my proposed solution, apple would not have unique abbreviation, because it doesnt exist, so the statement every w_i has at least one a_i, and that is w_i doesnt hold.
